# Are answers focusing on one aspect of a complex multi-part question acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I had an answer which did answer one paragraph of a multiple-part question. It also included a bit of other possibly irrelevant commentary. In my opinion that doesn't make it less of an answer and certainly doesn't mean it isn't an answer at all.

Perhaps the moderators should put some time into improving the questions if they cannot determine which answers apply to the question?

Comments?

Comment: Don't just wave your hands, link specific questions you are complaining about and why.

Answer (score 9):

I've read your answer and I fully agree with the deletion. It was converted to comment, a perfectly valid, if not slightly merciful, action on the part of the mods. Were I a mod in this case I would have deleted it outright.

Your answer was pretty well completely off topic to the question. Instead of answering the question "how common is detect evil in the forgotten realms" you launch into what I'm calling an "ad-alignmentium argument". Attacking the alignment system in D&D. That's part of the RAW there, if you don't want to play with it in your campaigns, that's fine, but Forgotten Realms games exist in the forgotten realms and should get answers with the flavor from that setting, not an attack on the alignment system.

I'm not seeing you answering *any* part of the question, but using the opportunity to answer as a jumping off point to attack both the alignment system and Paladin mechanics, you provide an alternative, but that's not really helpful to the OP who is asking for an in universe explanation/description. He's not the DM; changing the mechanics isn't an option here.

All that to say, welcome to the site and we value your contributions, all that we ask is that you keep them targeted to the question at hand, not to your own motivations for answering.

Comment: I have reviewed the answer and agree.

Comment: Yeah. You're somewhat at the mercy of the question not being 100% coherent - the question in the question isn't the question in the title and there's probably ~3 questions muddled together in there - but your answer didn't rise to the level of coherent answer, if I had seen it I would have converted or deleted or downvoted it too.  Sorry man.

Answer (score 7):

As one who flagged it for moderator review as not-an-answer, there's an important distinction that might not be obvious to new users.

The word "answer" has two relevant senses:

1. A response, or reply, to a question or statement. Hence, a volley in a back-and-forth conversation. "I answered his challenge with my own."
2. A solution to a problem, a statement that satisfies or attempts to satisfy requirements previously stated. "The answer to the problem was difficult to find, but obvious in hindsight."

The answers users may submit here at StackExchange are of the second sense. Users who are more familiar with discussion forums often erroneously assume "answer" here is in the first sense, synonymous with "reply" fields at the bottom of forum threads.

Your answer didn't seem to me to be an answer in the problem-solving sense, but instead an answer in the conversation sense. Since we only allow answers in the solution sense, I flagged it as not being an answer (solution) to the question posed.